# PHP avoid putting value in array

Tags: php, arrays

So lets say I have this line in my php script:
`array_push($arr,array($a,$b,$c));`
Lets say sometimes I have a `$b1` variable to put in this array
I would like to not have duplicate for the sake of maintenance how can I avoid doing this:
```

```
if(!isset($b1)){
    array_push($arr,array($a,$b,$c,$d));
}
else{
    array_push($arr,array($a,$b,$b1,$c,$d));
}
```

```

Comment: do you want to extend `$arr`, or to put another array in it, and where exactly `$b1` comes from. You have to be a bit more specific, and have description on how to reproduce your example.

Comment: ``$b1`` is just intended to be optional, ``$arr`` is a array of arrays, i am passing ``$arr`` over to javasciprt later where it is used to generate a table; ``$b1`` is a optional column in this case

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have came up with
I was hoping for some kind of syntax trick I did not know about.
I believe this works the same as Marko Mackic's solution but without using `@` to suppress errors, however if there was a actual need to have null values in the array this is not a solution.

```
function skipNull($in){
    $out=array();
    foreach($in as $val){
        if($val!==null){
            array_push($out,$val);
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
//skip part where variable are defined 
array_push($arr,skipNull(array(
    $a,$b,
    isset($b1)?$b1:null,
    $c,$d
)));
```

Comment: well yeah `@` can be short for `isset` :) it's the same solution, and my solution doesn't supress errors, because if a variable is not defined, you get the notice